# Magento add to cart not working on Samsung Galaxy tab (weird)

Tags: android, magento

does anybody know a solution for below issue? 
My magento webshop works great on all mobile devices except for the samsung galaxy tab. The add to cart function doesn;t work. If I use chrome on the same device it works fine.

Magento 1.6.2

Comment: I too confirm this is a problem with Magento CE1.7 and below on a Galaxy tablet 10.1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a problem where users with a Galaxy Tab couldn't login.
The solution was to enlengthen the session lifetime for Magento.

You can do this with the following option:

```
System -> Configuration -> Web -> Session Cookie Management -> Cookie Lifetime
```

You should also make sure the time on your Galaxy Tab is set to the right date/time and you should also check the server.

Comment: Did you make sure Javascript and cookies are enabled on your device for the specified browser? You might want to try to update the prototype version, but you will have to test that, because Magento might depend on the older version.